# Tortoise SVN update recursively

Tags: svn

i have used tortoise svn to partially checkout from a repository using the option "immediate children, including folders".

now i want to add the rest of the repo fully recursively, but when i just use "update" i still dont get those files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click the folder, go to **Tortoise SVN -> Update to Revision**. Change the depth to **fully recursive** then update:

[image]

Comment: I was wandering if it is possible to set fully recursive as default